# display: none not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I have tables located within a DIV and when the page initially loads, has `'display: none'` set.

There is a drop down menu, that when an item is selected shows the DIV.

This functionality works fine on the computer, but doesn't work on mobile.

I just want a very simple way to make this work, even if it's not using the same method.

```html
<div id="this_div" style="display: none"> ... </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function unHide() {
    document.getElementById('this_div').style = "";
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without knowing your code. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: You need a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add detailed and readable code, so we can understand problem

Comment: Why must everyone down vote? I put the code and realized it was hiding.

Comment: Use element.style.display="block" instead as its more reliable

Comment: document.getElementById('this_div').style.display = "block"; ? And this will work on mobile you believe?

Comment: Doesn't work on mobile still :/

Comment: @MikeValentino That definitely works on mobile. If you're still not seeing it, you either have JS disabled or something else in your HTML/CSS is hiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that javascript is active on your mobile browser ?
Try to add an `alert("Javacript is ON")` in your function to check this point.

I usually see on other's people code the use of "display:none" combined with "visibility:hidden". This command may be better understood by your mobile browser than the lone "display" ... So both together should be tested.

One off-topic consideration, to keep your code simple and clear, i suggest you define a css class that will hide your elements :

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Only need to add or remove this class to do your job. For adding :

```
document.getElementById("this_div").className += " hidden"
```

For removing :

```
document.getElementById("this_div").className.replace(/\bhiddden\b/,'');
```

So there will be no more 'style=""' in your HTML tags, only class and ids definition.

If you don't mind working with jQuery, it will surely reduce many of your difficulties (and make you writing less code !)